# What is 'round in "Gather ’round and listen close"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, morphology

In page 11 of this book: [Algorithms](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf#page=11) by DPV a line confused me:

> Gather ’round and listen close.

I thought it means to come close and listen carefully, but I get stuck by the `'round` form. Does it mean around? Why can an English word start off with punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is "around," and the reason for the apostrophe is that it's a contraction. ('Tis and 'twas also both get the initial apostrophe , though they are old-fashioned.)